# SQL Rollup Hierarchy Closest

Tags: sql

[image]

I have the following scenario. As you could see Levels (1) – ItemNumber (NULL) is the incoming number, which all the ones listed below are associated to the main one.
Ultimately, what I want to do is only get the following rows
Lines 2 and 4,5,6
Since row 2 doesn’t have any children rows and USDAFoodItemID is not null

And 4,5,6 The parent row 3 does have children, and since row 3 is null,
The children 4,5,6 will be spit out.

If Line 1 was populated with USDAFoodItemID then it would only spit out line 1.

Sorry for my English, I am still working on it. But help is universal, and I would appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Sorry, here is the code to produce the table.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, here is the code to produce the table. I am using MS SQL

DECLARE @HoldTable TABLE
(
Levels INT,
ItemNumber INT,
IngredientNumber INT,
NutritionalLoss FLOAT,
StandardAmountInGrams FLOAT,
SequenceNumber INT,
USDAFoodItemID NVARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @HoldTable VALUES (1,   NULL,   1174258,    1.0000  ,113.3980925    ,1, NULL)
INSERT INTO @HoldTable VALUES (2,   1174258,    1174252 ,1.0000,    113.3980925,    1,  09096)
INSERT INTO @HoldTable VALUES (3,   1174252,    1006967,    1.0000, 56.69904625,    1,  01297)
INSERT INTO @HoldTable VALUES (3,   1174252,    1174251,    1.0000  ,56.69904625,   1,  NULL)
INSERT INTO @HoldTable VALUES (4,   1174251,    1007555 ,1.0000 ,1.41747615625, 1   ,12078)
INSERT INTO @HoldTable VALUES (4,   1174251,    1010210,    1.0000, 26.93204696875, 1   ,NULL)
INSERT INTO @HoldTable VALUES (4,   1174251,    1010984,    1.0000, 28.349523125,   1   ,NULL)

SELECT * FROM @HoldTable

Thank you